# Caulking on roof

Tags: leak, roof, waterproofing

[image]

The edge were my roof meets the house has been leaking. I thought that I might be able to seal it by running caulking along the seem. Is this a bad idea? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The large amount of water up under the soffit indicates a problem further up the roof. That overhang probably has a valley above it, or some other structure, and it's not shedding water correctly.

The step flashing along the wall seems ok. It shouldn't need caulk, and caulk probably wouldn't help anyway. (Caulk is only useful for very small roof repairs.)

For more help, update your post with additional photos showing the bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way. Caulking is used by carpenters for sealing joints between dissimilar materials (or between similar materials) but roofing mastic is used on roofing.

However, there are a bunch of places it could be leaking into your house:

1) Step Flashing: step flashing must be laced into shingle courses and have the wall siding (and wall building paper) extend over the top of the step flashing. When people tell us "their roof is leaking" we often find that the wall is leaking and water is running down behind the wall building paper and step flashing. Make sure the step flashing and roof building paper extends up the wall (6"-8") far enough the wind can't blow rain up over the top of the step flashing. If you're worried that it could blow up there, use mastic (it comes in tubes like caulking) and apply a bead between the wall building paper and step flashing. Do not use caulking.

2) Wall and Soffit Above: Again, check to make sure wall building paper laps onto soffit so moisture can't get behind wall building paper. If no paper at joint between wall and soffit, I'd remove both and install paper to lap on top of wall paper.

3) Soffit Vent above: Yes, wind can blow water into roof vent and it could run on top of Soffit material to wall and then down behind wall building paper.

4) Wall at Top of Sloped Roof: Its seems unlikely, but if it's leaking at the top of the slope, water will run down the roof until it finds a way out.